# как в jQuery классе выбрать определенный элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу найти как в классе выбрать определенный элемент

Answer (score 1):

**1)** CSS - селектор, два элемента через пробел... означают, следующий находится где-то внутри предыдущего:

```
$('.class1 .class2 #id3 div')....
```

**2)** `.find()` тоже находит элемент, где-то внутри предыдущего

```
$('.class1').find('.class2')

// Что прикольно, можно использовать с this  

$(this).find('.class');
```

---

Может я не так понял...

```
$('.class').eq(0); // — Первый элемент на странице с таким классом...
$('.class').eq(1); // — Второй элемент...
$('.class').eq(2); // — Третий и т.п.
```

Есть еще такой вариант записи:

```
$('.class:eq(0)');
```

Comment: Спасибо 3 помогло

Comment: @Смешарики ответ примите.